# Can I access Outlook calendar via POP or similar server?

Tags: outlook, server, exchange-server, microcontroller, pop3

I'm doing a micro-controller project. I know how to access email via a POP server.  That part is easy.  What I would like to do is access an Outlook calendar via some similar method.  Is this possible?

Comment: I think this Stack Exchange site: http://superuser.com/  would be more suitable to ask this question.

Comment: Thanks I think I will repost over there.

Comment: Avoid repost, delete this one and post there or do not repost. It is not well received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No POP3 won't work for that, [Exchange Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900168(v=exchg.150).aspx) will be the easiest choice probably.